# Substitute words with underscores of the word's length, using python's re.sub method?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

How can I substitute words in a text to underscores with the same length, using python's re.sub method?

For example, `"hello ** abc"` should become `"_____ ** ___"`, which is five underscores, followed with `"**"` and then three underscores.

So far, this is what I have got:

```
 re.sub(r'\w+', '_', 'hello ** abc')
```

And this one below, when I try to refer to the matched words, does not work

```
re.sub(r'(\w+)',len(\1)*"_", 'hello ** abc')
```

[Edit] An alternative way would be using re.search to first find the words, and then substitute with `'_'*len(word)`. I wonder if we can do this job with `re.sub()` in one pass?

Comment: Search for the word and replace it with `'_'*len(word)`

Comment: That is fine. But you would need to find a way to reference to the word. Can we do that with re.sub, without search beforehand?

Comment: `re.sub(r'\w', '_', var)` should work

Comment: `re.sub('\\w', '_', 'hello ** abc')` results in `'_____ ** ___'`, which is exactly what you ask, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
import re
print( re.sub(r'\w+', lambda x: "_" * len(x.group()), 'hello ** abc') )
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/pm4pNE).

**Notes**:

- `(` and `)` in the pattern are not necessary. Wrapping the whole pattern with a capturing group only makes sense with `re.split` when you want to keep separators in the result, or in `re.findall` to just get the captured part(s), or `pandas.Series.str.extract(all)` to actually get the match, but in `re.sub`, when you need to get a match without further drillthrough, you need not capture the whole match another time
- `lambda x: "_" * len(x.group())` is a callable used as a replacement argument where the match value is accessed via `x.group()`, the `len(...)` gets the match length and `"_" * len(...)` creates a substitution string that only contains `_` chars that is the same length as the match value.